# Can't git push in parallel after merge using SHA1

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, gitlab

I'm trying to git push in parallel after merging branches

```js
function checkout(branch) {
    execSync(`git checkout origin/${branch}`);
}
async function merge(target, source) {
    let hadExceptions = false;
    let hadConflict = false;
    try {
        execSync(`git merge origin/${target} -m "AutoMerge Bot: Merged ${target} into ${source}"`);
    } catch (error) {
        if (error.stderr && error.stderr.length > 0) {
            console.log(error.stderr.toString());
            hadExceptions = true;
        }
        if (error.stdout && error.stdout.length > 0) {
            console.log(error.stdout.toString());
            //* When it's a merge conflict we do not treat the error as exception as it's expected behavior
            if (error.stdout.includes(MergeConflictMessage)) {
                await createMergeConflictCard(source, target);
                //* If we don't abort the merge we won't be able to checkout
                hadConflict = true;
            } else {
                hadExceptions = true;
            }
        }
        execSync("git merge --abort");
    }
    return {
        hadExceptions,
        hadConflict
    };
}
async function push(currentSHA, source) {
    const remote = `<remote>`;
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        exec(`git push ${remote} ${currentSHA}:${source}`, {
                maxBuffer: 10000000
            },
            (error, stdout, stderr) => {
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error.toString());
                }
                //* We get specific stderr when push is successfull
                if (stderr && !stderr.includes("View merge request for")) {
                    console.log(stderr.toString());
                }
                if (stdout) {
                    console.log(stdout.toString());
                }
                if (error) {
                    reject(error);
                    return;
                }
                resolve(stdout);
            });
    });
}
async function handleMergeRequests(mergeRequestBranches) {
    let promises = [];
    let exceptions = [];
    for (const {
            source_branch,
            target_branch
        } of mergeRequestBranches) {
        try {
            checkout(source_branch);
            const {
                hadConflict,
                hadExceptions
            } = await merge(target_branch, source_branch);
            if (hadConflict || hadExceptions) {
                exceptions.push({
                    source_branch,
                    hadExceptions
                });
                continue;
            }
            const currentSHA = execSync(`git rev-parse HEAD`);
            promises.push(push(currentSHA, source_branch));
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error.toString());
            if (error.stdout) console.log(error.stdout.toString());
            if (error.stderr) console.log(error.stderr.toString());
            if (error.stderr) {
                exceptions.push({
                    source_branch,
                    hadExceptions
                });
            }
        }
    }
    await Promise.all(promises);
    if (exceptions.length > 0) {
        throw new Error("Encountered error, check above for more info");
    }
}
```

For successful merges i get an error:

```
Error: Command failed: git push <remote> b9c4d95dc9408c072bbbd487110fee13a2f42c01:testing/martin/auto_merge_4

fatal: b9c4d95dc9408c072bbbd487110fee13a2f42c01 cannot be resolved to branch
```

I also tried to do:

```
git push <remote> testing/martin/auto_merge_4:testing/martin/auto_merge_4
```

Without any better results:

```
error: src refspec testing/martin/auto_merge_4 does not match any
```

Also tried:

```
git push <remote> HEAD:testing/martin/auto_merge_4
```

With result:

```
! [rejected]                  HEAD -> testing/martin/auto_merge_4 (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to '<remote>'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
```

Pulling didn't help

What am i doing wrong?

as a note, i'm trying to push from inside gtilab job to gitlab hosted repository.

I have tried various combinations but none of them seem to work,

Comment: use need to use -f to force push
`git push <remote> HEAD:testing/martin/auto_merge_4 -f`

Comment: @aRvi this will mess up the pushes when checking out as HEAD changes when switching branches and merging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to use a hash ID on the left (source) side of a push refspec, it's wise to use a *full name* on the right side:

```
git push <remote> <hash>:refs/heads/br/an/ch
```

for instance.  The `refs/heads/` part, now explicitly spelled out, is *implied* when the left side name is a branch name, but a raw hash ID is not a branch name.  (It's not a tag name either, so if you wish to have the other Git create a *tag* name, spell that out with `refs/tags/na/me/of/ta/g` or whatever.)

---

As for:

```
error: src refspec testing/martin/auto_merge_4 does not match any
```

This just means that in the left side of the refspec—the part before the colon—could not be matched to either `refs/heads/testing/martin/auto_merge_4` *or* `refs/tags/testing/martin/auto_merge_4`.  Your Git therefore has no idea whether this is supposed to be a branch, a tag, or something else, *and* it has no idea what hash ID to use either.  A more typical `git push` would read:

```
git push <remote> <name>
```

and the *`name`* part implies that the refspec is `name:name`.  Your Git then tries the *`name`* as tag first, then branch, and if one of those two works, knows to ask the other Git to set a tag, or a branch.

Comment: Indeed that worked, but i want to add one more note as i ran into another issue when getting SHA1 from `execSync` output. It had new line character which would obviously not work when trying to work.

Comment: @Arin: I always forget to strip the newline in code, and then spot the error when I test it. :-)